# Calculate the difference between two date entries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the number of days between dates stored in MYSQL, taking into account different date ranges in different records.

Here is a sample table:

```
 tableID   User     Start_Date   End_Date
 -------   ----    ----------   ----------
    1      111     2015-09-09   2015-09-15
    2      111     2015-09-01   2015-09-02
    3      111     2015-09-16   2015-09-21
```

Expected result:
Since tableID 1 and 3 have consecutive days the result should be **11**.
I'm bad at explaining things so if you don't get the problem please comment below.

Comment: add whatever you have tried

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: what if we have record like starte_date 2015-09-22 and end_date 2015-09-30?

Comment: What Consecutive days , you are talking about? can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Consecutive days like in the table the tableID  1 has an End_Date of 2015-09-15 and the Start_Date of tableID 3 has a start_Date of  2015-09-16.

Comment: What is your expected output? 2,11?

Comment: @JoSSte yes! that is exactly myexpected output

Comment: I don't think that is doable in a simple way. I am assuming that your key is the user? do the records have any unique identifier so that you can sort them out?

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Comment: Why should result be 11?

Comment: @JoSSte yes they do have a unique identifier, the tableID

Comment: @fancypants : 2015-09-09 -> 2015-09-15  + 2015-09-16 -> 2015-09-21 

6 + 5 = 11

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably start by copying everything to a temp table, then moving the records that don't fulfill `end_date = start_date +1`, then running through the rest, updating them so that the start_date and end_date for all sequences are in the same record

So something like this:

**Temp_table_1**

```
tableID   User     Start_Date   End_Date
-------   ----    ----------   ----------
   1      111     2015-09-09   2015-09-15
   2      111     2015-09-01   2015-09-02
   3      111     2015-09-16   2015-09-21
   4      111     2015-08-16   2015-08-21
   5      111     2015-07-16   2015-07-21
```

*Move non-sequential records to temp_2*

**Temp_table_1**

```
tableID   User     Start_Date   End_Date
-------   ----    ----------   ----------
   1      111     2015-09-09   2015-09-15
   3      111     2015-09-16   2015-09-21
```

**Temp_table_2**

```
tableID   User     Start_Date   End_Date
-------   ----    ----------   ----------
   2      111     2015-09-01   2015-09-02
   4      111     2015-08-16   2015-08-21
   5      111     2015-07-16   2015-07-21
```

*Consolidate the records*

**Temp_table_1**

```
tableID   User     Start_Date   End_Date
-------   ----    ----------   ----------
   x      111     2015-09-09   2015-09-21
```

*Move consolidated records to temp 2 and calculate difference*

**Temp_table_2**

```
tableID   User     Start_Date   End_Date   Diff
-------   ----    ----------   ---------- ------
   2      111     2015-09-01   2015-09-02    2
   4      111     2015-08-16   2015-08-21    5
   5      111     2015-07-16   2015-07-21    5
   x      111     2015-09-09   2015-09-21   11
```

Have a look, attempt to write a procedure, and update your question to ask for more help if you get stuck.

Comment: I'll try this! Thank you for the help, sorry I am not good at explaining problems.

Comment: Practice makes perfect, and an effort to try will often be rewarded.